# Are those interrogative 'wh' sentences constructed correctly?

Tags: questions, interrogatives, who-whom

sentences:

> 1) To **whose** bag should I attach the ticket?
>
> 2) To **whose** speech should I pay his attention?
>
> 3) To **whom** did you refer this article?
>
> 4) To **whom** does he send the letter?

question:

> Are those interrogative 'wh' sentences constructed correctly?

Comment: I'm not sure number 2 is quite correct. What are you trying to say? Unless the inclusion of "his" is accidental?

Comment: @SteveES To whose speech should I pay his attention? = I want him to pay his attention to speech but I want to find out to what/whose exactly speech among all the speeches I should pay his attention

Comment: Do you mean "To whose speech should **he** pay attention?"? Or "To whose speech should I tell him to pay attention?"? - To clarify, what is **your role** and what is **his role**?

Comment: The second one is more fits the occasion: To whose speech should I tell him to pay attention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your sentences, except number 2 (which I will come onto shortly), **are grammatically correct, but are a formal way of asking the question**. In an informal context, or when speaking, the "wh" word tends to come first and the preposition tends to come at the end, e.g.

> 1) Whose bag should I attach the ticket to?

---

Number 2 is grammatically incorrect, because **he** pays **his** attention, **you** cannot *pay* **his** attention, you can only *direct* his attention or *instruct* him to pay attention. This is because you are not in control of "his attention" and pay is synonymous with "give". You can't *give* his attention to something, you can only *tell him* what to do with it. Number 2 should therefore be either something like:

> To whose speech should I **direct** his attention?

Or something like:

> Whose speech should I tell him to pay attention to?

(The second one sounds much better to me with the preposition at the end, which is why I have phrased it like that). For what it's worth, I think the first version is better.

---

As an additional aside, "whom" is very rarely used in informal or spoken English, most natives would use "who" instead (and many wouldn't know the difference between the two, and when to use "whom").

Answer (score 2):

The sentences are grammatically correct and idiomatic.

Your question, though, is a word-salad.  Did you mean:

> Are those interrogative 'wh' sentences constructed correctly?

Comment: Yes. I wanted to ask about one sentence, then i had changed my mind and added 's' to the word 'sentence'. thanks

Comment: @Max - yes the is/are agreement was a problem, but not a serious one.  The real issue was "right constructed".  I am guessing that in your native language that phrase is idiomatic, but in English, it is almost indecipherable.  You could say, "Are those sentences _rightly constructed_?" in English (although it would sound stiff) but as it was, I could only guess at your meaning.